# SQL : unrecognized name

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, where-clause, data-analysis, where-in

Unrecognized name: year at [6:7]

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM starttime) AS year,
    COUNT (*) AS number_of_rides
FROM
  bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips 
WHERE year IN
  (2013,2014)
GROUP BY
  year
ORDER BY
  year DESC
```

--wanted to return data in 2013 and 2014

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use aliases defined in your select clause within your where-, group- and order-clauses in Google Bigquery. You need to spell out the function again. Replace each `year` in your clauses by `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM starttime)` and it should work.

Comment: Doesn't Google Bigquery accept column aliases in the ORDER BY clause?

Comment: possible actually. Might even be ok in the group. definitely no on the where though.